# Blazor WASM ASP.Net Hosted HTTP requests not reaching endpoints, returns index.html

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-apicontroller

I have a ASP.Net Core hosted Blazor WASM app that makes calls to the Server API.
Most of the time, communication works completely fine, and data is exchanged without problems.
However, in some cases, the server returns the content of `index.html` without hitting the endpoint.

Example controller:

```cs
[HttpGet(Routes.GroupStage.GetGameDays)]   // resolves to api/v1/groupstages/{id}/gamedays
public async Task<IActionResult> GetGameDays(
    [FromRoute] Guid id,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var query = new GetGameDaysQuery(GroupStageId: id);
    var result = await Sender.Send(query, cancellationToken);
    return result.IsFailure
        ? HandleFailure(result)
        : Ok(result.Value);
}
```

The really weird part is, that the controller is getting hit, if the model with a specific `id` does not exist. However, it is **not** getting hit when it actually does exist.

Is there any reason for this type of behaviour?

Changing the `GetGameDays`-route, (e.g. to `api/v1/groupstages/{id}/gamedayss` fixes the routing issue. But I would still want to know *how* and *why* this unexpected behaviour occurs.

Comment: 1. Check other endpoint routes, 2. check GetGameDaysQuery for internal error, 3. add try catch to find the bug, if exist bug on code. 4. add breakpoint to controller constructor to make sure its hit by all call endpoints.

Comment: 1. Other endpoint routes work. 2. No internal error, since it is not even hit, see above. 3. No bug found, no errors, no console outputs that indicate anything. 4. As described above, no error. The endpoint is hit when ID of a non-existent entity is given, but not if one of an existing entity is given.

Comment: Based on the code provided this question cannot be answered. Please provide enough information to reproduce the error.

Comment: I agree with jeb, if you want to fix the issue, it's better to provide a sample which could reproduce the issue. And please hide the sensitive information.

Answer (score 0):

When testing the requests in a different environment (Postman), the routing worked as expected, excluding any error on the server side.
After checking the Network tab in my browser, I found out, that the request is fulfilled by (disk cache).
Deactivate caching, test request ... works as expected now.

**Rant incoming**: Why in the world would it even do such thing? And what is the procedure there? "Hey, there *maybe* was a time when the controller for the given route was not there, so lets just return the fkn `index.html`, no cache busting"?

**TLDR**: Deactivate Browser caching

**Related follow-up topic:** Is there any 100% guaranteed way to update web applications, let alone PWAs, ensuring the latest up to date content is served without kindly asking the client's browser to not cache anything?